# uint64_t or int64_t not found error when compiling gcc-7.3.0

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc, linux-from-scratch

I am building my own linux system from scratch.

As I am a beginner I don't know much about the error, and I've tried some ways, but still I am unable to solve this. I came across a step to compile gcc.

The command I used to compile is

```
CC=$LFS_TGT-gcc \
CXX=$LFS_TGT-g++\
AR=$LFS_TGT-ar \
RANLIB=$LFS_TGT-ranlib \
../gcc-7.3.0/configure \
--prefix=/tools \
--with-local-prefix=/tools \
--with-native-system-header-dir=/tools/include \
--enable-languages=c,c++ \
--disable-libstdcxx-pch \
--disable-multilib \
--disable-bootstrap \
--disable-libgomp
```

When I run `make` it gives the following error

```
Configuring in ./gcc
configure: creating cache ./config.cache
checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
checking LIBRARY_PATH variable... ok
checking GCC_EXEC_PREFIX variable... ok
checking whether to place generated files in the source directory... no
checking whether a default linker was specified... no
checking whether a default assembler was specified... no
checking for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc... x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu-gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu-gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu-gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... no
checking whether x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu-g++AR=x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu-ar accepts -g... no
checking for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gnatbind... no
checking for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gnatmake... no
checking whether compiler driver understands Ada... no
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... /lib/cpp
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... no
checking for sys/types.h... no
checking for sys/stat.h... no
checking for stdlib.h... no
checking for string.h... no
checking for memory.h... no
checking for strings.h... no
checking for inttypes.h... no
checking for stdint.h... no
checking for unistd.h... no
checking minix/config.h usability... no
checking minix/config.h presence... no
checking for minix/config.h... no
checking whether it is safe to define __EXTENSIONS__... no
checking how to run the C preprocessor... x86_64-lfs-linux-gnu-gcc -E
checking for inline... no
checking for special C compiler options needed for large files... no
checking for _FILE_OFFSET_BITS value needed for large files... unknown
checking for _LARGE_FILES value needed for large files... unknown
checking size of void *... 0
checking size of short... 0
checking size of int... 0
checking size of long... 0
checking for long long... no
checking for int8_t... no
checking for int16_t... no
checking for int32_t... no
checking for int64_t... no
checking for long long int... no
checking for intmax_t... no
checking for intptr_t... no
checking for uint8_t... no
checking for uint16_t... no
checking for uint32_t... no
checking for uint64_t... no
checking for unsigned long long int... no
checking for uintmax_t... no
checking for uintptr_t... no
configure: error: uint64_t or int64_t not found
Makefile:4186: recipe for target 'configure-gcc' failed
make[1]: *** [configure-gcc] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/mnt/lfs/sources/old-gcc'
Makefile:902: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

**Can anyone help me to solve this?
Any ideas are appreciated.**

Comment: Bold adventure. I don’t know where you got your command from, but `--disable-bootstrap` seems wrong to me if you want to build gcc from scratch.

Comment: You should look at the file `config.log` to see exactly what the configure script is trying to do and where it failed.

Comment: I don't understand when seeing the config.log file ,So i'll give you the config.log file,can you please help me to solve this?
There is no space in comment to include the file, So you inbox to my mail ID, I'll give the config.log file. My personal mail ID: **r.prabhuome2@gmail.com** you messages are welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at this output you will see "configure" is not able to find some headers :

```
checking for ANSI C header files... no
checking for sys/types.h... no
checking for sys/stat.h... no
checking for stdlib.h... no
checking for string.h... no
checking for memory.h... no
```

And on my system I have this header file.
So, I suspect, you're system need at this step to find those headers to be able to compile "gcc"

```
ls -l /usr/include/stdlib.h
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 34030 Aug  7  2019 /usr/include/stdlib.h
```

Seem like you have try to say to "configure" that your header is located there :

```
--with-native-system-header-dir=/tools/include
```

Please double check configure.log if the right "-I" was used by the compiler, and this header exist.