# An error occurs when gcc-8.2.0 is compiled with MinGW On stage 2 uint64_t or int64_t not found

Tags: gcc, g++, mingw

I am building the gcc-8.2.0 with MinGw, but on stage 2, configure in gcc, There is a problem like the following：

```
Configuring stage 2 in ./gcc
configure: loading site script /mingw32/etc/config.site
configure: loading cache ./config.cache
checking build system type... i686-w64-mingw32
checking host system type... i686-w64-mingw32
checking target system type... i686-w64-mingw32
checking LIBRARY_PATH variable... ok
checking GCC_EXEC_PREFIX variable... ok
checking whether to place generated files in the source directory... no
checking whether a default linker was specified... no
checking whether a default assembler was specified... no
checking for i686-w64-mingw32-gcc...  /d/qt-everywhere-src-4.08.5/gcc/./prev-gcc/xgcc -B/d/qt-everywhere-src-4.08.5/gcc/./prev-gcc/ -B/usr/distributes/mingw32/i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ -L/usr/distributes/mingw32/i686-w64-mingw32/lib -L/usr/distributes/mingw32/mingw/lib -isystem /usr/distributes/mingw32/i686-w64-mingw32/include -isystem /usr/distributes/mingw32/mingw/include -B/usr/distributes/mingw32/i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ -B/usr/distributes/mingw32/i686-w64-mingw32/lib/ -isystem /usr/distributes/mingw32/i686-w64-mingw32/include -isystem /usr/distributes/mingw32/i686-w64-mingw32/sys-include
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.exe
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables... .exe
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether  /d/qt-everywhere-src-4.08.5/gcc/./prev-gcc/xgcc -B/d/qt-everywhere-src-4.08.5/gcc/./prev-gcc/ -B/usr/distributes/mingw32/i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ -L/usr/distributes/mingw32/i686-w64-mingw32/lib -L/usr/distributes/mingw32/mingw/lib -isystem /usr/distributes/mingw32/i686-w64-mingw32/include -isystem /usr/distributes/mingw32/mingw/include -B/usr/distributes/mingw32/i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ -B/usr/distributes/mingw32/i686-w64-mingw32/lib/ -isystem /usr/distributes/mingw32/i686-w64-mingw32/include -isystem /usr/distributes/mingw32/i686-w64-mingw32/sys-include    accepts -g... yes
checking for  /d/qt-everywhere-src-4.08.5/gcc/./prev-gcc/xgcc -B/d/qt-everywhere-src-4.08.5/gcc/./prev-gcc/ -B/usr/distributes/mingw32/i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ -L/usr/distributes/mingw32/i686-w64-mingw32/lib -L/usr/distributes/mingw32/mingw/lib -isystem /usr/distributes/mingw32/i686-w64-mingw32/include -isystem /usr/distributes/mingw32/mingw/include -B/usr/distributes/mingw32/i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ -B/usr/distributes/mingw32/i686-w64-mingw32/lib/ -isystem /usr/distributes/mingw32/i686-w64-mingw32/include -isystem /usr/distributes/mingw32/i686-w64-mingw32/sys-include    option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether  /d/qt-everywhere-src-4.08.5/gcc/./prev-gcc/xg++ -B/d/qt-everywhere-src-4.08.5/gcc/./prev-gcc/ -B/usr/distributes/mingw32/i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ -nostdinc++ -B/d/qt-everywhere-src-4.08.5/gcc/prev-i686-w64-mingw32/libstdc++-v3/src/.libs -B/d/qt-everywhere-src-4.08.5/gcc/prev-i686-w64-mingw32/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/.libs  -I/d/qt-everywhere-src-4.08.5/gcc/prev-i686-w64-mingw32/libstdc++-v3/include/i686-w64-mingw32  -I/d/qt-everywhere-src-4.08.5/gcc/prev-i686-w64-mingw32/libstdc++-v3/include  -I/d/qt-everywhere-src-4.08.5/gcc-8.2.0/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++ -L/d/qt-everywhere-src-4.08.5/gcc/prev-i686-w64-mingw32/libstdc++-v3/src/.libs -L/d/qt-everywhere-src-4.08.5/gcc/prev-i686-w64-mingw32/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/.libs accepts -g... yes
checking for i686-w64-mingw32-gnatbind... /d/qt-everywhere-src-4.08.5/gcc/./prev-gcc/gnatbind
checking for i686-w64-mingw32-gnatmake... gnatmake
checking whether compiler driver understands Ada... no
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... /lib/cpp
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... no
checking for sys/types.h... no
checking for sys/stat.h... no
checking for stdlib.h... no
checking for string.h... no
checking for memory.h... no
checking for strings.h... no
checking for inttypes.h... no
checking for stdint.h... no
checking for unistd.h... no
checking minix/config.h usability... no
checking minix/config.h presence... no
checking for minix/config.h... no
checking whether it is safe to define __EXTENSIONS__... no
checking how to run the C preprocessor...  /d/qt-everywhere-src-4.08.5/gcc/./prev-gcc/xgcc -B/d/qt-everywhere-src-4.08.5/gcc/./prev-gcc/ -B/usr/distributes/mingw32/i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ -L/usr/distributes/mingw32/i686-w64-mingw32/lib -L/usr/distributes/mingw32/mingw/lib -isystem /usr/distributes/mingw32/i686-w64-mingw32/include -isystem /usr/distributes/mingw32/mingw/include -B/usr/distributes/mingw32/i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ -B/usr/distributes/mingw32/i686-w64-mingw32/lib/ -isystem /usr/distributes/mingw32/i686-w64-mingw32/include -isystem /usr/distributes/mingw32/i686-w64-mingw32/sys-include    -E
checking for inline... inline
checking for special C compiler options needed for large files... no
checking for _FILE_OFFSET_BITS value needed for large files... unknown
checking for _LARGE_FILES value needed for large files... unknown
checking size of void *... 0
checking size of short... 0
checking size of int... 0
checking size of long... 0
checking for long long... no
checking for int8_t... no
checking for int16_t... no
checking for int32_t... no
checking for int64_t... no
checking for long long int... no
checking for intmax_t... no
checking for intptr_t... no
checking for uint8_t... no
checking for uint16_t... no
checking for uint32_t... no
checking for uint64_t... no
checking for unsigned long long int... no
checking for uintmax_t... no
checking for uintptr_t... no
configure: error: uint64_t or int64_t not found
make[2]: *** [Makefile:4358: configure-stage2-gcc] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/d/qt-everywhere-src-4.08.5/gcc'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:26746: stage2-bubble] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/d/qt-everywhere-src-4.08.5/gcc'
make: *** [Makefile:957: all] Error 2
```

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.
Found some methods, but it seems to have no effect， like this: [uint64_t or int64_t not found error when compiling gcc-7.3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60787159/uint64-t-or-int64-t-not-found-error-when-compiling-gcc-7-3-0)
this is my configure options

```
CXXFLAGS=-static CFLAGS=-static LDFLAGS=-static  CXXFLAGS_FOR_TARGET=-static CFLAGS_FOR_TARGET=-static LDFLAGS_FOR_TARGET=-static ../gcc-8.2.0/configure --prefix=/usr/distributes/mingw32 --with-native-system-header-dir=/usr/distributes/mingw32/i686-w64-mingw32/include --libexecdir=/usr/distributes/mingw32/i686-w64-mingw32/  --with-arch=i686 --with-tune=generic --enable-languages=c,lto,c++ --enable-bootstrap --enable-shared --enable-static --enable-libatomic --enable-threads=posix --enable-graphite --enable-fully-dynamic-string --enable-libstdcxx-filesystem-ts=yes --enable-libstdcxx-time=yes --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-libstdcxx-debug --disable-isl-version-check --enable-lto --enable-libgomp --disable-multilib --enable-checking=release --disable-rpath --disable-win32-registry --disable-nls --disable-werror --disable-symvers --disable-plugin --with-libiconv --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld --disable-sjlj-exceptions --with-dwarf2
```

Comment: In MinGW `uint64_t` or `int64_t` need `#include <stdint.h>`.

Why are you building such an old version of GCC?

Comment: Yes, I know, but I don't know why It didn't find this file correctly, use this version of the compiler is used for compatibility with older code，There are some compatibility problems with too high a version，If I disable this option[--disable-bootsrap], there will be no problem compiling, but I am not sure whether this option is necessary.

Comment: I have been able to compile Qt 4.8.7 with GCC 10.2.0 (from http://winlibs.com/), but I have to say it took quite some tweaking.

Comment: Wow, that’s great. I have spent several weeks researching on this, but I haven’t succeeded so far. I’m still doing more attempts to see if there are other better solutions.

Comment: But then again, how do you know that I am going to compile the early Qt source code

Comment: The path `/d/qt-everywhere-src-4.08.5/gcc` gave it away ;-)